# Turn AngularJS test helper into package

Tags: npm, bower

I have a bunch of test helpers for angularjs that I'm using in several projects. I want to pack them into a npm or bower module/package, to easily reuse and share them. But I'm not sure, what the proper way to do is.

A helper looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var spyHelper = angular.module("spyHelper", []);
  spyHelper.factory("spyOnPromise", ["$q", "$rootScope", function($q, $rootScope) {
    return function(service, functionName, args) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var spy = spyOn(service, functionName).andReturn(deferred.promise);
      spy.resolve = function(value) {
        deferred.resolve(value);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        return spy;
      }
      spy.reject = function(value) {
        deferred.reject(value);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        return spy;
      }
      return spy;
    }
  }]);
  beforeEach(module("spyHelper"));
})();
```

And it is used inside my tests like this:

```
describe('myService', function () {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var spyOnPromise, myService;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_spyOnPromise_, _myService_) {
    spyOnPromise = _spyOnPromise_;
    myService = _myService_;
  }));

  it("should revolve a promise", function() {
    spyOnPromise(myService, "fetch").resolve();
    // ... do some other stuff
  });
});
```

The helper itself is in a spec helper file, that gets included inside `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
  // ....
  'test/helper/**/*.js',
  // ...
],
```

**So my questions are:**

1. The helper are injected as modules, and this is kinda annoying. I'm using jasmine, and it would be cool to extract them into some jasmine helpers (e.g. I don't have to inject something to use jasmines' `expect(...)` method). Whats the proper way to do this? Because I need angulars' `$q` and `$rootScope` modules, and I think inside jasmine they wouldn't be available. Am I right?
2. Should I pack the whole thing into a bower or a npm module/package?
3. I also have some test helpers that extend jQuery for testing purposes. What would be the right way to bundle them into some reusable test helper modules?

Any links to tutorials, code samples, resources are welcome!

## Update

Currently I have the following solution:

```
(function() {
  var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  var $q = injector.get("$q");
  var $rootScope = injector.get("$rootScope");

  this.spyOnPromise = function(service, functionName, args) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var spy = spyOn(service, functionName).andReturn(deferred.promise);
    spy.andResolveWith = function(value) {
      deferred.resolve(value);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      return spy;
    };
    spy.andRejectWith = function(value) {
      deferred.reject(value);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      return spy;
    };
    return spy;
  };
}).call(this);
```

With this solution, you can simply write in your tests `spyOnPromise(...)`, and you don't have to inject the whole thing again and again.

What do you think, is this approach OK? Or is there a better solution?